# quanteda - calculating sparsity proportion of top n features

Tags: r, quanteda

I'm trying to get the top n features of a corpus and then check the sparsity proportion of the top n features. However, my coding does not work well because sparsity work only with dfm objects, but if I put sparsity() after `dfm_remove(stopwords("en"))` I could not know the proportion of the top features.
Could you please tell me some suggestions for my case?

Thank you in advance for your help!

```
  top_n_terms <- text %>% 
      tokens(remove_numbers = TRUE, remove_punct = TRUE, remove_symbols = TRUE) %>% 
      tokens_ngrams(n = 1:3) %>% 
      dfm() %>% 
      dfm_remove(stopwords("en")) %>% 
      topfeatures(n = 3000) %>% 
      sparsity()
```

Answer (score 0):

First, create the dfm as you have, then limit it to the top `n` features using `dfm_trim()`, then send that result to `sparsity()`.

So:

```r
dfm_trim(your_dfm, min_termfreq = n, termfreq_type = "rank") %>%
  sparsity()
```

where in your example if you want the sparsity of the dfm with just the 3,000 most globally frequent terms, then substitute `3000` for `n`.

Comment: Thank you a lot @Ken!
The suggestion helps me well. 
Have a nice day!